# Error importing HDF .h5 catvsnoncat data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, h5py

I am trying to import coursera catvnoncat dataset in python from [here](https://www.floydhub.com/deeplearningai/datasets/cat-vs-noncat/1/train_catvnoncat.h5).

I ran the following code

```
with h5py.File("https://www.floydhub.com/deeplearningai/datasets/cat-vs-noncat/1/train_catvnoncat.h5","r") as hdf:
    ls=list(hdf.keys())
    print(" Dataset in file",ls)

h5py.File("https://www.floydhub.com/deeplearningai/datasets/cat-vs-noncat/1/train_catvnoncat.h5","r") as hdf:
    ls=list(hdf.keys())
    print(" Dataset in file",ls)
```

I wanted to print the imported datasets, but got:

> OSError:OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'https://www.floydhub.com/deeplearningai/datasets/cat-vs-noncat/1/train_catvnoncat.h5', errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

Comment: You can't access the data remote from that platform, but you've to download it and serve it for any application from your own local or public server. I will propose this question for deletion.

Comment: How  do you then download .h5 dataset ? I am new to Python and HDF

Comment: Just go to the links you provided and download the files manually. put the data on your server and adjust the links to show to these local copies.